# How to create ElementFinder in WatiN?

Tags: watin

In WatiN RC1 how can I create ElementFinder which will find any element on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found out.

I can create ElementFinder using two ways

First. When creating custom control (extending Div, Table and so on) there is a protected method `CreateElementFinder<T>`. Here is an example:

```
var elementFinder = CreateElementFinder<Element>(
    nativeEl => nativeEl.AllDescendants,
    Find.ById("id"));
```

Second. If you are not extending any control you can use NativeElementFinder constructor. Here is an example:

```
var finder = new NativeElementFinder(
    () => browser.Body.NativeElement.AllDescendants,
    browser.DomContainer,
    new[] { ElementTag.Any },
    Find.ById("id"));
```